# Compositional advantage of Lodash/Underscore syntax over vanilla JS syntax

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

I'm familiarizing myself with some of the Lodash/Underscore methods and have a fundamental question about syntax.

---

If I have a list of user objects and want to filter the list by those users whose ages are less than 40, I can write the following vanilla JavaScript:

```
// Vanilla JS
var result = users.filter((d) => d.age < 40);
```

LoDash/Underscore offers an alternative syntax to produce the same result:

```
// Lodash, Underscore
var result = _.filter(users, (d) => d.age < 40);
```

Both of these produce the same result and return an array.

**What are the compositional advantages, if any, to using the latter syntax? Why is it preferable to using the plain JS syntax?**

---

**Edit**

Because I'm receiving answers like "one requires an additional library and one doesn't" and "they execute different code", I want to clarify.

**From a [function composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition_(computer_science)) standpoint, are there any advantages to using the lodash/underscore method over the Vanilla JS method?**

Comment: Well, in using the former you are writing in Vanilla JS as opposed to using a library. Dependencies per Vanilla: 0. So the *advantages* are relative, IMO, as this is merely library vs vanilla. No different than jQuery vs vanilla. Pick your poison.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I'm looking for the advantages from a composition standpoint.

Comment: The difference is that one uses the library's function and the other uses the vanilla JS function. They are executing different code (that in this case do the exact same thing).

Comment: @MatthewHerbst, as I indicated above, I'm looking for the compositional advantages.

Comment: What do you mean by "compositional advantages"?

Comment: Building functions that allow the building of more complicated functions or behavior through reuse or combination.

Comment: the fp module of lodash is the one that you might be interested on, for a pure functional library you should check out [Ramda](http://fr.umio.us/why-ramda/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you have the following function `compose`.

```
function compose(f, g) {
  return function apply(...args) {
    return g(f(...args));
  }
}
```

You can use it to compose two functions together to create a single function.

```
const inc = x => x + 1;
const double = x => x * 2;

const doubleAndInc = compose(double, inc);
doubleAndInc(3) // 7
const incAndDouble = compose(inc, double);
incAndDouble(3) // 8
```

These functions can be composed because **they only rely on their arguments**. The same is true for Lodash's `filter` function.

```
const filterFirst = compose(_.filter, _.head);
filterFirst([1, 2, 3], x => x % 2 == 0); // 2
```

`Array.prototype.filter` isn't called with an array as an argument. Instead, it uses its internal `this` value—which will usually be the array the method was called on.

The `compose` function doesn't know anything about `this`. It only works with arguments and return values, which means it can't be used to compose functions that rely on `this` instead of just arguments.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the to-the-point response.